# tomcat7 application fails to deploy on linux

Tags: java, tomcat7, web-deployment

I have war file. It works fine on windows, and fails on tomcat7 in Linux. I can't obviously catch this in remote debugger and there is no info in other files. Here is the stacktrace.

Any ideas what I can do?

> SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/tr
>   iptop-sender]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1074)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:554)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1649)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
>           at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1447)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:679)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:437)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>           at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.CharsetMapper.(CharsetMapper.java:81)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.CharsetMapper.(CharsetMapper.java:61)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getCharsetMapper(StandardContext.java:1492)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5269)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>
> ```
>     ... 37 more
> ```

Comment: Is this the whole StackTrace?

Comment: @Zarathustra, Yes, you can see text "...37 more" that is generated by printStackTrace() method...

Comment: The bug is gone. I am redeploying app and now I don't see it. Very strange thing.

Comment: In case you get it again .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039049/severe-containerbase-addchild-startorg-apache-catalina-lifecycleexception-fa