# Tomcat server does not run in localhost

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, localhost

The Apache Tomcat server is started but it does not open in the browser (i.e. localhost) giving 404 error.

Tried changing port no in server.xml, then changing server location to Tomcat installation but nothing worked. Eclipse gives these errors while starting the Tomcat server, shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Instead of pasting screenshot, you should paste the error message instead.

Comment: SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.9-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\webapps\ROOT
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:

Comment: You have to offer more information for identifying problem. For example : http://stackoverflow.com/q/35224311

Answer (score 0):

This usually only happens if your configuration is screwed up or the mapping from your IDE to your webapp folder. I would set server.xml back to normal. Then verify your web.xml file is in the correct location and configured properly. Look it up in your eclipse config and see if eclipse is actually finding it. Sometimes if your IDE does not find web.xml then when it builds you get a 404.

You can rule out your IDE by building your WAR then running it directly in Tomcat without eclipse.