# Spring Web Project failed to started in tomcat server environtment

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat8, zk

I have found other stackoverflow questions similar to this one. I've tried to solving may problem from their answered. But it's not worked for my case....so i try to post a question here...

in my cases , I have compiled web project ( WAR ) using spring, zk and java. my workspace project is in my laptop. I'm using IDE Eclipse and Tomcat as a webserver.

before i deploy my war project to environment server , i've always try to deploy and running in may local eclipses and local tomcat.

everything running well in my laptop, but in server environment tomcat failed to started the application.

My Laptop using Win10 and :

```
**Tomcat**
version 8.5.61

**Java** :
java version "1.8.0_271"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)
```

My Server :

```
**Tomcat**
Version 8.5.29

**Java**
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)

**OS**
Distributor ID: SUSE LINUX
Description:    SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
Release:        11
Codename:       n/a
```

This is the error when deployed in server environment

```
2021-08-05 13:03:08.116 ERROR 18908 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication  : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(logs/spring.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: logs/spring.log (Permission denied)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:169)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:82)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:290)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:263)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:226)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:199)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5204)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

05-Aug-2021 13:03:08.123 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/my-aceh]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(logs/spring.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: logs/spring.log (Permission denied)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:169)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:82)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:290)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:263)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:226)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:199)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5204)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more

05-Aug-2021 13:03:08.125 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat_61010/webapps/my-aceh.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/my-aceh]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

05-Aug-2021 13:03:08.126 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat_61010/webapps/my-aceh.war] has finished in [7,127] ms
```

**UPDATE 06/08/2021**

after setting permission on spring.log , the message error failed to load component still come out.

```
06-Aug-2021 22:33:41.112 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat_61010/webapps/my-aceh.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/my-aceh]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

06-Aug-2021 22:33:41.113 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat_61010/webapps/my-aceh.war] has finished in [7,127] ms
```

thank u for your support...

Comment: The log message itself a self-explanatory which tells `FileNotFoundException: logs/spring.log (Permission denied)`, change the permission of the directory or change to the accessible log path

Comment: thank u, i've tried the solution for logs/spring.log ... but for the next error message still occurs when i'm trying to deploy.... 
start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component

Comment: Can you post your Maven file? You may be running into something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224311/severe-containerbase-addchild-start-org-apache-catalina-lifecycleexception-f if you used the Spring Boot starters for Tomcat on your local machine.

Comment: Please don't modify your question by adding other problems unrelated to the original one: post a new question instead. The cause of the new problem has certainly been logged to either `spring.log` or `localhost.<date>.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in your logs files, Spring can not create the file `logs/spring.log` (relative to the server's working directory). Unless your system administrator changed the usual permissions on a Tomcat installation:

- `$CATALINA_BASE/logs` **is** writable by Tomcat, but
- there is **no** guarantee that the OS working directory of the server is `$CATALINA_BASE`, although often it is.

To be on the safe side and don't depend on Tomcat's working directory, use the Java system property `catalina.base` to define the path of the log file:

```
logging.file.name=${catalina.base:.}/logs/spring.log
```

The fallback `.` is used when you start your application in an embedded Tomcat.

**Remark:** Since you use the default `spring.log` file name, you can also delete the `logging.file.name` property an configure just a path:

```
logging.file.path=${catalina.base:.}/logs
```

Comment: Thank u , on my leave  i share this solution to my member teams and the apps running well till now...

thank u...

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace it seems like tomcat is trying to create a file under `logs/spring.log` in the tomcat directory which the using running tomcat not has access to. See `(Permission denied)` in the stacktrace.

You could create this file and give write access for the user running tomcat.

Comment: yes thank u , i've tried created and make it accessible for the user running tomcat..there is no error related to spring.log but still failed to start component

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons may happen:
Check if you have permission to read the `spring.log` file or not this is the most obvious reason for java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Access is denied) exception so immediately provide read, write and execute permission to the log file and try again.

Or check if some other process is using that file This could be another possible reason for java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Access is denied).

Comment: Do you get a stacktrace now? If yes, can you please post it?