# Glassfish 4: deploy problems when building with Maven

Tags: maven, ant, glassfish

I am having issues deploying a project that was converted from ant to maven, on Glassfish 4. When I generate a war file with my build.xml, I can deploy it without any problems, but when I make the war file with Maven and try to deploy it, I get the following exception:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 48188.
```

I would assume that there is some problem in the pom.xml file. I'll pastebin it here, but it is quite a big file (the project uses a lot of dependencies), so I'm not sure if it will be of much help. What could be causing that exception?

The pom.xml file:
http://pastebin.com/aQS2inaQ

Att.

*Chris Michaels*

Comment: I think this will help u.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039049/severe-containerbase-addchild-startorg-apache-catalina-lifecycleexception-fa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039049/severe-containerbase-addchild-startorg-apache-catalina-lifecycleexception-fa)

Comment: Sadly, none of those solutions applied to my problem.

Att.

Chris Michaels

Comment: Your pom needs a lot of cleanup. The default scope for dependencies is `compile` so you are packaging tons of stuff which shouldn't be there, like all your test frameworks which should have `test` scope, plus all the JSRs which are provided with GlassFish and will conflict. (it would be a good idea to replace the individual JSR dependencies with just the Java EE 7 coordinates:   `<dependency> 
   <groupId>javax</groupId>   
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>   
    <version>7.0</version> 
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`

Comment: Could you also add the ***full*** error log from maven, rather than just that one line?

Comment: That line is the full error log, it's all the information glassfish gives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the contents of the 2 WARs created by Ant and Maven. The list of jar files in `WEB-INF/lib` should be similar. I guess that the maven version contains much more than the Ant version.

You should give `provided` scope to the dependencies that provide only API that is already available in GlassFish:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
  <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.ejb</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.7</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
  <version>1.11</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Or just remove those dependencies and replace them with

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
  <version>7.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you, that actually helped.

My particular issue was with one particular jar inside the war file, icu4j.jar. A verification in the mvn dependency tree showed me that the file came from jaxen 1.1.1. Using jaxen 1.1.6 instead removed that jar from the dependencies and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- What is the jdk version of galssfish server ?
- what is the jdk version of you use to build the application ?
- Did you add maven dependencies to your project ?
- After updating maven dependencies some times the Jre system library
  changes in the application automatically.so did u check the
     jre system library version in java build path after updaing maven
     dependencies ?