# Tomcat 7 WAR Deployment (Spring Boot) - Failed to start component

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I ran into an issue when deploying my WAR to tomcat. I've tried adding several exclusions and various dependencies from other threads but none have worked. I am using an outdated version of javax.servlet due to the fact that it won't accept any version any higher than 2.5 (get undefined error in Intellij) but I don't think this is an issue. I have ran mvm clean in intellij. I'm not sure what else I can do here, I've been editing my pom.xml file continuously for hours.

**catalina.out:**

```
Dec 12, 2018 8:52:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/pino-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/pino-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1021)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:993)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1815)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1514)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:278)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:198)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:603)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1136)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Dec 12, 2018 8:52:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
```

**pom.xml:**

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.pino.db</groupId>
<artifactId>pino</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>pino</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Spring MVC class:

```
package com.pino.db.pino;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PinoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(PinoApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PinoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use tomcat 8.5 or higher for spring boot 2.1 deployment

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look to the Spring Boot documentation : [Create a Deployable War File](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file)

> ### Create a Deployable War File
>
> [...]
>
> The first step in producing a deployable war file is to provide a
>   `SpringBootServletInitializer` subclass and override its `configure`
>   method. Doing so makes use of Spring Framework’s Servlet 3.0 support
>   and lets you configure your application when it is launched by the
>   servlet container. Typically, you should update your application’s
>   main class to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`, as shown in the
>   following example:
>
> ```
> @SpringBootApplication
> public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
>
>   @Override
>   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
>       return application.sources(Application.class);
>   }
>
>   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
>       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
>   }
>
> }
> ```
>
> The next step is to update your build configuration such that your
>   project produces a war file rather than a jar file. If you use Maven
>   and `spring-boot-starter-parent` (which configures Maven’s war plugin
>   for you), all you need to do is to modify `pom.xml` to change the
>   packaging to war, as follows:
>
> ```
> <packaging>war</packaging>
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The final step in the process is to ensure that the embedded servlet
>   container does not interfere with the servlet container to which the
>   war file is deployed. To do so, you need to mark the embedded servlet
>   container dependency as being provided.
>
> If you use Maven, the following example marks the servlet container
>   (Tomcat, in this case) as being provided:
>
> ```
> <dependencies>
>   <!-- … -->
>   <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
>       <scope>provided</scope>
>   </dependency>
>   <!-- … -->
> </dependencies>
> ```

### EDIT

IMO, your `pom.xml` should look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.pino.db</groupId>
    <artifactId>pino</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>pino</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: If you take a look at my pom file, I have war set as the packaging type, and the scope for starter-tomcat is provided. In my code, I also have the application builder (class does extend initializer) exactly as described above, only thing different is my application name.

Comment: I have updated the description with the application class

Comment: Well, it's not exactly the same. Why do you need provided `servlet-api` with `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` in your `pom.xml` instead of provided `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` ?

Comment: I included the servlet-api as per this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039049/severe-containerbase-addchild-startorg-apache-catalina-lifecycleexception-fa

but it did not solve my issue.

Comment: I updated my pom file and am still getting the same error :( although the pom file is a lot cleaner and I do see why it functions the same